# Tempered fundamental solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

According to the Malgrange–Ehrenpreis theorem every nontrivial linear constant coefficient PDO $P(\partial)$ admits a fundamental solution $E\in\mathscr{D}'$; I wonder whether $P(\partial)$ admits a *tempered* fundamental solution, namely a $E\in\mathscr{S}'$ with $P(\partial) E=\delta_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this has been demonstrated by L. Hörmander in 1958 ('On the division of distributions by polynomials', Arkiv för Matematik Band 3, nr 53; Theorem 5). In fact he showed the division problem tempered distributions; and proved that *if $P$ is a polynomial that does not vanish identically, the multiplication mapping $\mathscr{S}\rightarrow\mathscr{S}$ defined by $f\mapsto Pf$ admits a continuous inverse.* From this result the rest easily follows.